# Add multiple entries to list and get order

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I create multiple CustomNodes with `Buttons` on an `AnchorPane`.
My Nodes are created on `Button` click,e.g. when I click on the Button 'task1' a new Node with a `Label` 'task1' and a ID will be created.
These CustomNodes have multiple tasks(e.g. task1, task2), and they will be created on different `Button` events.
I have a `ArrayList` where I store these ID's (but I store all ID's in the same List).

Can I store two items in one List index (id + function)? Like when I press on the task1 `Button` I want to store the id and function task1 in the same index. And when I press task2 `Button`, I want to store the id + task2 function right behind but in the same List.

And another point of my question is can I get the order of ID's? I connect my Nodes via `CubicCurves`, in this Link class I have my function:

```
public void bindEnds (DragNode source, DragNode target) {
//Code above
        source.registerLink (getId());
        target.registerLink (getId());
}

public void registerLink(String linkId) {
    mLinkIds.add(linkId);
}
```

Where I register my source and target CustomNodes.
On my Nodes are two `Circles` (on the left and right). The left `Circle` is supposed to be the input, the right output. I want to check if my left/right `Circle` is connected . If the left is not connected but the right, it should be the first Item in my list. If both are connected, I need the order and store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a class that will store id and task like this :

```
public class Stocker {
private Task task;
private int id;
public Stocker(Task task, int id) {
this.task = task;
this.id = id;
}
public Task getTask() {
return task;
}
public int getId() {
return id;
}
}
```

and then change your list like this :

```
List<Stocker> stockers = new ArrayList<Stocker>();
```

you can now create a stocker with :

```
Stocker stocker = new Stocker(task,id);
```

store it with :

```
stockers.add(stocker);
```

and access your values using :

```
stockers.get(index).getId();
//or
stockers.get(index).getTask();
```

Comment: Your comment seems to lead me to the solution, but what I called task is more a function, like function1();. I'm sorry I called it task, do you know how to change this?

Comment: Like Stocker(String funcname, String id), and then get the String name to call a function?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I don't understand what you are asking for, are you trying to store a function and get it later ?

Comment: I want to link a function to a button where i create my nodes, so when I create the node with function1, the special id should be linked to this function

Answer (score 0):

The library http://www.javaslang.io/ has already defined the type Touple, that is exactly what you want, but if you do not want to add a new library, just build the object yourself. A simple pojo with two attributes (id and function) should do the trick.